# ¿Cómo obtener los elementos de un 'select' que se crearon con la librería Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, select2

Cree un select (dropdownlist) con la librería 'select2' el cual consiste en que cada elemento del select (dropdownlist) que selecciono me lo guarda, ahora bien, intenté, obtener los elementos seleccionados de la siguiente manera, pero no logré conseguirlo, cómo pondría obtener los elementos (texto) del listado que he seleccionado

```
    var user ='';
    var usuarios ='';
    user = $.map($('#visualizacionPreg tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:eq(8) select option'), function (e) { return e.value; });
    usuarios = user.toString();
```

Ese es el select (dropdownlist) que creé

```
<td><select class="select-combo  js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"></select ></td>'
```

El texto que dice 'alimay@secuencia.com' es el que quiero obtener, pues es el elemento que seleccione.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es un problema de HTML+JavaScript, por lo que debería ser posible replicar lo que quieres en la propia pregunta. StackOverflow permite añadir snippets de código pulsando en el icono `<>` del editor. Por favor, dale a [edit] y crea un [mcve] con el que podamos ver el problema concreto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude, encontré la función "`.select2('data')[0].text;`"

```
    var user ='';
    var usuarios ='';
   user = $('#visualizacionPreg tr:eq(' + i + ')').find('td:eq(8) .select-combo').select2('data')[0].text;
```